# Starlette FormData only provides names of files but not actual files

Tags: python, forms, file-upload, fastapi, starlette

Trying to upload multiple files through a dynamic HTML form using FastAPI.

Server-side, the form comes through okay (as type `starlette.datastructures.FormData`) but the files are not coming through. all i can see are the filenames as strings.

As per the [docs](https://www.starlette.io/requests/), if i try:

```
@app.post("/modules/function")
async def function(request: Request):
    form = await request.form()
    filename = form["upload_file"].filename
    contents = await form["upload_file"].read()
```

it fails with `'str' object has no attribute 'read'` on line 4.

From the docs, `form["upload_file"]` is supposed to be type `starlette.datastructures.UploadFile` but i am getting it as type `str` .

Seemingly obvious solution is to declare files in path, but since form is dynamic, i can't tell how many files will be coming each time, so i need to be able to retrieve them from the `FormData` .

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Simple error. include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in html form tag. It doesn't automatically default to this when you include a file upload.